# Where can i configure the max_allowed_packet in hostgator or godaddy

Tags: php, mysql, execution

I am running a web application in hostgator.

my MySQL is reruns the

## 2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query

I found the some of the solutions in the stack overflow i.e.

Configuring my.ini file

[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=16M

But my doubt is in my localhost i found the my.ini file but in hostgator or godaddy hosting sites where can i configure these configuratrion

Please help me out this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't - it's a server setitng.

Comment: Then how can i solve this problem

Comment: Get your server host to change it.